# get A1Notation of unprotected range on google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to get the range  of a unprotected cells of a sheet in A1Notation?
I have this function but don't show me the A1Notation, and I don't know what more do:

```
 function parametrosdeProceso() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var hoja = ss.getSheetByName("KMD108");
var protection = hoja.protect();
var unprotected= protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
 
Logger.log(unprotected);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, for one sheet

```
function listOfUnprotectedRanges() {
  var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => r.getA1Notation())
  console.log(ranges)
}
```

for the whole spreadsheet

```
function listOfUnprotectedRanges() {
  var p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  p.forEach(x => {
    var ranges = x.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => r.getA1Notation())
    console.log(ranges)
  })
}
```

Comment: Btw, you can get the `ranges` with just one line: `var ranges = p1.getUnprotectedRanges().map(r => r.getA1Notation())`

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I'm still not familiar with map(). Answer updated!

Comment: I believe you know the 'map()' already since it is exactly the same as 'forEach()'. Except it returns a new array right away. No need to create the array beforehand and fill the array inside the loop.

Comment: @MikeSteelson , your code is great,  I'm really want understand the code.     
 Can you tell me why you put [0], to the end of the  second line?

Comment: See here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection-type , second example `Removes sheet protection from the active sheet`for instance. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)` is an array of only one element [0]

Comment: sorry, the right explanation is that here I use `getProtections()` on active sheet, if you use `getProtections()` on the spreadsheet you will find as many items as protected sheets inside your spreadsheet

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the use for multiple sheets